# Memory management of UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, uigesturerecognizer

Given one example here, ( with ARC )

```
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];

        [subView1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture ];
        [subView2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Here is the problem:

subView1 will not response to the tapGesture , but subView2 will.

subView1 will work if we remove tapGesture from subview2.

What happens inside in terms of memory management ?  Why not design to make above code work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im quite sure that the standard gesture recognizers included in iOS can only be attached to one view at a time. I can't find anything that states it explicitly but if you look at the `UIGestureRecognizer` class there is a `view` property with this description:

> The view the gesture recognizer is attached to. (read-only)

So my guess is that `addGestureRecgnizer:` will unattach the reconizer if it's already attached to a view.

Comment: no this is not exactly true just look at this example I found on net [net](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture)

Comment: Ok, but isn't that a custom gesture recognizer that is not included in iOS as default? i only stated that none of the standard ones support more than one view (but maybe iOS 6 or later will have them, i don't know).

Comment: I had a look at the code in your GIT repository (why did you commit a zip file instead of the source code files btw?) and I can't see how that had anything to do with this? of course the recognizer actions can to things with multiple views. The original question was if one recognizer instance can be used to recognize gestures in multiple views.

Comment: oh.. i just have understand it wrongly or interpreted it other way sorry for that.

Comment: Coolcoo, actually the original question was about memory handling but the reason why it behaves that way.